# Ajax request to cloud run service that requires authentication

Tags: ajax, cors, google-cloud-run

I'm having a CORS related issue with google cloud run on a service that
requires authentication.

If I try to execute a curl command through the cli, with a Bearer token,
everything works fine.
Unfortunately if I try to execute the same call through ajax in javascript,
I receive a 403.

```
  const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url = 'https://my-app.run.app';

  http.open("GET", url);
  http.withCredentials = true;
  http.setRequestHeader("authorization", 'Bearer ' + id_token);
  http.send();
  http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    console.log(http.responseText)
  }
```

The error in the cloud run logs is this :

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating
```

The container is never hit.

The issue I'm seeing is that, as I'm making the call using ajax, in a web
browser. The web browser is making a pre flight request ( OPTIONS on the
url ) without sending the Authorization header ( which is an expected
behavior )

The problem seems to be that cloud run tries to authenticate the OPTIONS
request and never makes it to my container, which, as far as I understand,
shouldn't be done.  (
https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0 )

Is that a known issue with cloud run ?

How could I make an ajax request to an authenticated cloud run service ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Cloud Run PM)

This is a known issue. There are a few options:

1. Allow unauthenticated requests and do CORS/auth yourself

   1. There is a variation of this that uses [Cloud Endpoints running on Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run) in front of your compute. Have Endpoints do your end-user auth, then forward the request to your backend.
2. Serve from the same domain (e.g. use the [Firebase Hosting proxy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run))

We've considered implementing [Istio `CORSPolicy`](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/virtual-service/#CorsPolicy), which would return CORS headers before the auth check, though we're not committed to this as of now.

Comment: The firebase Hosting Proxy seems like a reasonable work around. Thanks